# Can I save preferences in savedInstanceState

Tags: sharedpreferences

I am developing a real estate application where users will require to constantly change the preferences to tune their searches. i.e The user may want to change the location of their search, price range and number of bedrooms. Since these values are constantly changing I was thinking savedOnstanceStates are better than SharedPreferences but I am unable to implement it. Any useful link or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Saving the instance state and shared preferences are not the same thing.  I reject the former option for the simple reason that when the user exits the app, his preferences would not be persisted when he opens the app again later.  Shared prefs seems like a good way to go here.

Comment: Actually I wanted the preferences to be deleted when the user exits the app.

Comment: Saving the instance state is for things like preserving the state of an activity across rotations, and also for coming back to an activity after completing another one.  But, it may not work for all your use cases.